# In Eclipse, can I make the layout scrollable if my minimum SDK is 10?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, android-2.3-gingerbread, vertical-scrolling

My physical phone runs Android 2.3.3., so I'm developing with a minimum SDK of 10. According to the project creation wizard in Eclipse, that's apparently just *one* short of being able to choose a Navigation Type besides None.

I want my new app to be scrollable -- how do I do this? For example, can I put my content inside a scrollable element inside the layout parent element?

Comment: Yes, you can. No matter what is your minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a ScrollView as parent of your layout.

```
<ScrollView>
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"

     <LinearLayout> 
         // your Layout
     </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). And it works for API level 10 too ...

Comment: hey was that useful ??

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not marking anything sooner, I'm a "StackOverflow twice a day at most" person. Your solution just took some fussing around because my version of Eclipse doesn't have it built-in and I'm just getting the basics of XML.